# How to stop my Footer div more than width of page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Fist post on here, forgive me if I do something wrong.

I've copied a tutorial for a navigation bar and copied the code and am modifying it to make it my own work. Any way, the only code that is my own is the Footer div I want at the bottom of the page, however whatever I set the width to it seems to go wider than I want it. A scroll bar appears in the window and have to use it to view the rest of the page.

I've tried using Width:100% and Width:auto, but can't seem to get it right.

Thanks in advance

```js
$(function() {
  /**
   * for each menu element, on mouseenter, 
   * we enlarge the image, and show both sdt_active span and 
   * sdt_wrap span. If the element has a sub menu (sdt_box),
   * then we slide it - if the element is the last one in the menu
   * we slide it to the left, otherwise to the right
   */
  $('#sdt_menu > li').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    var $elem = $(this);
    $elem.find('img')
      .stop(true)
      .animate({
        'width': '170px',
        'height': '170px',
        'left': '0px'
      }, 400, 'easeOutBack')
      .andSelf()
      .find('.sdt_wrap')
      .stop(true)
      .animate({
        'top': '140px'
      }, 500, 'easeOutBack')
      .andSelf()
      .find('.sdt_active')
      .stop(true)
      .animate({
        'height': '170px'
      }, 300, function() {
        var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
        if ($sub_menu.length) {
          var left = '170px';
          if ($elem.parent().children().length == $elem.index() + 1)
            left = '-170px';
          $sub_menu.show().animate({
            'left': left
          }, 200);
        }
      });
  }).bind('mouseleave', function() {
    var $elem = $(this);
    var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
    if ($sub_menu.length)
      $sub_menu.hide().css('left', '0px');

    $elem.find('.sdt_active')
      .stop(true)
      .animate({
        'height': '0px'
      }, 300)
      .andSelf().find('img')
      .stop(true)
      .animate({
        'width': '0px',
        'height': '0px',
        'left': '85px'
      }, 400)
      .andSelf()
      .find('.sdt_wrap')
      .stop(true)
      .animate({
        'top': '25px'
      }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #333 url(bg.jpg) repeat top left;
  font-family: Arial;
}

ul.sdt_menu {
  margin-top: 150px;
}

h1.title {
  text-indent: -9000px;
  background: transparent url(title.png) no-repeat top left;
  width: 633px;
  height: 69px;
}

ul.sdt_menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: "Myriad Pro", "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 1020px;
}

ul.sdt_menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

ul.sdt_menu li {
  float: left;
  width: 170px;
  height: 85px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.sdt_menu li>a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 85px;
  z-index: 12;
  background: transparent url(../images/overlay.png) no-repeat bottom right;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
}

ul.sdt_menu li a img {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 85px;
  z-index: 100;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
}

ul.sdt_menu li span.sdt_wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 15;
}

ul.sdt_menu li span.sdt_active {
  position: absolute;
  background: #111;
  top: 85px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 14;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
}

ul.sdt_menu li span span.sdt_link,
ul.sdt_menu li span span.sdt_descr,
ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box a {
  margin-left: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}

ul.sdt_menu li span span.sdt_link {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

ul.sdt_menu li span span.sdt_descr {
  color: #0B75AF;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 155px;
  /*For dumbass IE7*/
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 170px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 170px;
  top: 85px;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
  background: #000;
}

ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box a {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #0B75AF;
}

ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box a:first-child {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.footer {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 140px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main_content {
  background-color: orange;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <h1 class="title">Slide Down Box Menu with jQuery and CSS3</h1>
  <ul id="sdt_menu" class="sdt_menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="" />
        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
        <span class="sdt_wrap">
    <span class="sdt_link">About me</span>
        <span class="sdt_descr">Get to know me</span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" />
        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
        <span class="sdt_wrap">
    <span class="sdt_link">Portfolio</span>
        <span class="sdt_descr">My work</span>
        </span>
      </a>
      <div class="sdt_box">
        <a href="#">Websites</a>
        <a href="#">Illustrations</a>
        <a href="#">Photography</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="" />
        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
        <span class="sdt_wrap">
    <span class="sdt_link">Inspiration</span>
        <span class="sdt_descr">Where ideas get born</span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="" />
        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
        <span class="sdt_wrap">
    <span class="sdt_link">Photos</span>
        <span class="sdt_descr">I like to photograph</span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="" />
        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
        <span class="sdt_wrap">
    <span class="sdt_link">Blog</span>
        <span class="sdt_descr">I write about design</span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/6.jpg" alt="" />
        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
        <span class="sdt_wrap">
    <span class="sdt_link">Projects</span>
        <span class="sdt_descr">I like to code</span>
        </span>
      </a>
      <div class="sdt_box">
        <a href="#">Job Board Website</a>
        <a href="#">Shopping Cart</a>
        <a href="#">Interactive Maps</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="main_content">
  fffs
</div>
<div class="footer">
  home
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking at the snippet quick my guess would be you are picking up the margin/padding from the body.  I didn't move the snippets over to test but I think all you need to do is set left to 0 for the footer div.

```
.footer {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 140px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Change this class 
ul.sdt_menu{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            list-style: none;
            font-family:"Myriad Pro", "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
            font-size:14px;
            width:1020px;
            overflow: hidden;
            } 

 to


ul.sdt_menu{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            list-style: none;
            font-family:"Myriad Pro", "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
            font-size:14px;
            width:100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            }
```